# Token always showing up under NFTs

Tags: metaplex, nft, metadata

Solana newb here.

Curious how I would go about updating the metadata on my newly created token so that it is not showing up as an NFT on SolScan.

Is this an error in my initial creation?

Once I add MetaData via one of the 3rd party services it changes from "Market Overview" to "Fungible Asset Overview" in the overview section.

Any insight on what I am missing here would be super great, I am a bit out in the weeds at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if the token was created with 0 decimals it will end up getting displayed under the "NFT" section of a wallet. Not sure if that's the case with your scenario. Wallet's are really just UI, so how tokens are displayed are determined by each wallet.

Metaplex docs include a "token standard" that provides definitions for common terms used to describe tokens with certain characteristics.

> Whilst NFTs are the biggest use case of the Token Metadata program,
> it’s important to notice that the program also works with Fungible
> Token and, what we call, Semi-Fungible Tokens or Fungible Assets.
>
> At the end of the day, the Metadata account helps attach data to
> tokens regardless of their fungibility. However, the standard of the
> off-chain JSON file will vary slightly to accommodate their needs.
>
> To safely identify the fungibility of a token — and, thus, the
> standard that we should use — the Metadata account keeps track of that
> information in its Token Standard attribute. This attribute is
> automatically computed by the program and cannot be manually updated.
> It can take the following values.
>
> NonFungible: The Mint account is associated with a Master Edition
> account and, therefore, is Non-Fungible. This is your typical NFT
> standard.
>
> NonFungibleEdition: This is the same as NonFungible but the NFT was
> printed from an Original NFT and, thus, is associated with an Edition
> account instead of a Master Edition account.
>
> FungibleAsset: The Mint account is Fungible but has zero decimal
> places. Having zero decimals means we can treat the token as an asset
> whose supply is not limited to one. For instance, Fungible Assets can
> be used in the gaming industry to store resources such as “Wood” or
> “Iron”.
>
> Fungible: The Mint account is Fungible and has more than one decimal
> place. This is more likely going to be a token used as a decentralised
> currency.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview#semi-fungible-tokens
https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard